# mouse listener only one instance works

Tags: java, swing, components, awt, mouselistener

So i am setting mouse listeners to java components in the following manner:

```
int[] monsters = new int[12];
        monsters[0] = MonsterSelector.BL_BLUE_BUFF;
        monsters[1] = MonsterSelector.BL_RED_BUFF;
        monsters[2] = MonsterSelector.BL_WOLVES;
        monsters[3] = MonsterSelector.BL_WRAITHS;
        monsters[4] = MonsterSelector.BL_GOLEMS;
        monsters[5] = MonsterSelector.BARON;
        monsters[6] = MonsterSelector.PU_BLUE_BUFF;
        monsters[7] = MonsterSelector.PU_RED_BUFF;
        monsters[8] = MonsterSelector.PU_WOLVES;
        monsters[9] = MonsterSelector.PU_WRAITHS;
        monsters[10] = MonsterSelector.PU_GOLEMS;
        monsters[11] = MonsterSelector.DRAGON;    
for(int monster = 1; monster < MonsterSelector.LAST+1; monster++){
        final int currentMonster = monsters[monster-1];
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(images.get(currentMonster), 50, 50);
        ivs.put(currentMonster, iv);
        ivs.get(currentMonster).addMouseListener(this); 
    }
```

and i have the following implementation of mouselistener in my class:

```
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        Component src = (Component) e.getSource();

        Log.e(TAG, ""+src.getName());
    }
```

Now the problem is that only the first mouselistener set really gives the output. the rest just ignore. what am i doing wrong? i cant set the same mouselistener on multiple objects?

Comment: Same behaviour if you replace `ivs.get(currentMonster).addMouseListener(this);` with `iv.addMouseListener(this);`? Are you sure that `currentMonster` is different at each loop?

Comment: Could you post the code that initializes the `images` list and where your `MonsterSelector` constants are declared? If there's a problem in either one of those, it could be causing this issue.

Comment: what the deal with your weird looping idiom: `for(int monster = 1; monster < MonsterSelector.LAST+1; monster++)` ? why not start at 0 ?

Comment: How are these layout?? Do they overlap?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that either `MonsterSelector.LAST` isn't set to the highest value it should be. Or that you're initialising `MonsterSelector.BL_BLUE_BUFF`, `MonsterSelector.BL_RED_BUFF`, etc. to all have the same int value?